# Generate Annotation files Automatically in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, annotations

I am using `Annotations` and `svn`(Version control) in my application. I have created one package inside of my application and some Activities inside of it. Now the application is perfectly running. I just committed the files to svn and tried to `checkout` files from another one pc. Now my projects contain some errors. The errors happen whenever I use intent for calling new Activity that shows an error. The error says `"Summary_ cannot be resolved to a type"`(Here I mention summary is my Activity name).

And `I just add a space in that java file and save the error is gone`. But I can not ask other peoples to do this every time. Because this also happen whenever the eclipse is restarted or when I clean my project . Checkout from svn. Update svn.

I guess the annotation files are not generated. Please anyone help me to  solve this issue.

Note : `I just added a space(or whatever) in that java file and saved. the error is gone` . I want to know why it is happening?